# Apache Spark on EC2 "Killed"

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

My program, which I've run numerous times on different clusters suddenly stops. The log:

```
15/04/20 19:19:59 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 12.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 374) in 61 ms on ip-XXX.compute.internal (16/24)
15/04/20 19:19:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_44_14 in memory on ip-XXX.compute.internal:37999 (size: 16.0 B, free: 260.6 MB)
Killed
```

What does "Killed" mean and why does it occur? There's no other errors.

Answer (score 1):

"Killed" usually means that the OS has terminated the process by sending a SIGKILL signal.  This is an unblockable signal that terminates a process immediately.  It's often used as an OOM (out-of-memory) process killer -- if the OS decides that memory resources are getting dangerously low, it can pick a process to kill to try to free some memory.

Without more information, it's impossible to tell whether your process was killed because of memory problems or for some other reason.  The kind of information you might be able to provide to help diagnose what's going on includes: how long was the process running before it was killed? can you enable and provide more verbose debug output from the process? is the process termination associated with any particular pattern of communication or processing activity?

Comment: The process has run multiple times for hours. Now, however, it stops after maybe 20 seconds. It says there's about 255Mb of memory free per node. If I launch a new cluster then it works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled to false in your program's Spark config, something like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("YourProgramName").set("yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled","false")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-avoid-being-killed-by-YARN-node-manager-td22199.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe the vm problem

1. ensure you have swap partition.
2. ensure `vm.swappiness` is not zero.